# Update @StateObject every time that init() is invoked in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, state

I'm writing a SwiftUI code for a carousel, and I have a `CarouselModel` class that goes like this:

**CarouselModel.swift**

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class CarouselModel: ObservableObject {
    
    //MARK: - Properties
    @Published private var imagesCount: Int
    @Published private var currentImage: Int
    @Published private var offsetMainAxis: CGFloat
    private var screenSize: CGFloat
    private var isHorizontal: Bool
    private var padding: CGFloat
    
    private var nextImage: Int {
        return (self.currentImage+1) % self.imagesCount
    }
    
    private var prevImage: Int {
        return (self.currentImage-1+self.imagesCount) % self.imagesCount
    }
    
    private var centralIndex: CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(self.imagesCount-1)/2
    }
    
    public var computedOffset: CGFloat {
        return (centralIndex-CGFloat(currentImage))*(screenSize-padding) + offsetMainAxis
    }
    
    
    init(imagesCount: Int, isHorizontal: Bool = true, padding: CGFloat = 20, currentImage: Int = 0) {
        self.imagesCount = imagesCount
        self.currentImage = currentImage
        self.offsetMainAxis = 0
        self.padding = padding
        self.isHorizontal = isHorizontal
        if isHorizontal {
            self.screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        } else {
            self.screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
        }
    }
    
    
    //MARK: - Methods
    public func getCurrentImage() -> Int {
        return self.currentImage
    }
    
    public func goNext() -> Void {
        withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 0.5)) {
            currentImage = nextImage
        }
    }
    
    public func goPrevious() -> Void {
        withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 0.5)) {
            currentImage = prevImage
        }
    }
    
    public func onDragChange(offset: CGFloat) -> Void {
        self.offsetMainAxis = offset
    }
    
    public func onDragEnd() -> Void {
        if abs(offsetMainAxis) > 0.2*screenSize {
            if offsetMainAxis > 0 {
                withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 0.5)) {
                    offsetMainAxis = 0
                    currentImage = prevImage
                }
            } else {
                withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 0.5)) {
                    offsetMainAxis = 0
                    currentImage = nextImage
                }
            }
        } else {
            withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 0.5)) {
                offsetMainAxis = 0
            }
        }
    }
    
    public func skipTo(number i: Int) {
        withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 0.5)) {
            currentImage = i
        }
    }
}
```

At this point every time I need to place a concrete `Carousel` in my app I create a `CarouselView.swift` file containing `some View`, and the thing goes more or less like this:

**CarouselView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct Carousel: View {
    @StateObject var carousel: CarouselModel
    private var screenWidth: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    private var images: [String]
    private let padding: CGFloat
    private var descriptions: [String]?
    @State private var imageSelected: [String:Bool]
    
    init(images: [String], descriptions: [String]?, padding: CGFloat = 20) {
        self.images = images
        self.padding = padding
        _carousel = StateObject(
            wrappedValue:
                CarouselModel(
                    imagesCount: images.count,
                    isHorizontal: true,
                    padding: padding
                )
        )
                
        self.imageSelected = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: images.map{ ($0, false) })
        
        guard let desc = descriptions else {
            self.descriptions = nil
            return
        }
        self.descriptions = desc
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        // USE carousel TO DISPLAY SOME CAROUSEL IMPLEMENTATION
    }
}
```

Now, a problem arises when inside some container I need to display a different set of images based on a `@State private var selectedImgSet: Int` and each set has a different amount of pictures in it. The point is, whenever I call `CarouselView(...)` inside the container and its parameters change, its `init` is invoked but the `CarouselModel` doesn't get updated with the new images count.

This is totally expected since it is a `@StateObject` but I'm not sure how the update should happen. I can't use the `.onAppear(perform: )` hook in the CarouselView since that is executed only once, when the `CarouselView` first appears.

What is the correct way to update the `carousel: CarouselModel` variable whenever `CarouselView`'s `init` parameters change?

**EDIT:** Here are pastes for a full working examples: [ContentView](https://pastebin.com/Zq5rP0jF), [CarouselItem](https://pastebin.com/K0XQ1s1u), [CarouselModel](https://pastebin.com/eT4GZizN), [CarouselView](https://pastebin.com/XRd30mSF), [Items](https://pastebin.com/Cbbxv6Vd). Add the following images sets to your assets: item00, item01, item02, item10, item11, item20, item21, item22, item23. Any 1920x1080p placeholder will do the trick for now.

Comment: Could you provide a minimum reproducible example? It would help if we could see just how you are utilizing the carousel to display images. I do have a hunch as to what the issue is, but a working example would help. For reference, my test case involved adding a button that appends a new string to images array, and doing so successfully adds a new image to my view.

Comment: If init is called that means a new view is created. With a new carrousel object as it is created in init.

Comment: @nickreps: I added patebins for a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks. I am not seeing the variable you mentioned - @State private var selectedImgSet: Int

Comment: @nickreps that role is played by `@State private var selectedSet` from ContentView.swift file in my minimum example

Comment: It looks like you are initializing your carouselModel just once. You need to either 1) publish your count value from your model, and run a function to update it when your selectedSet value changes in your content view or 2) create a @Binding in your CarouselView that is bound to your selectedSet value.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually fixed my issue the following way: I introduced the following method in `CarouselModel`:

```
public func update(_ images: Int) {
    print("Performing update with \(images) images")
    self.imagesCount = images
    self.currentImage = 0
    self.offsetMainAxis = 0
}
```

Then I added to the outmost View inside `CarouselView` the following modifier:

```
.onChange(of: self.images) { v in
    self.carousel.update(v.count)
}
```

Now the update happens as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You've got things the wrong way round. Create the `@StateObject` in the View above `Carousel` View and pass it in as `@ObservedObject`. However, since your model does no loading or saving it doesn't need to be a reference type, i.e. an object. A value type will suffice, i.e. a struct, so it can be `@State` in the parent and pass in as `@Binding` so you can call its mutating functions.